# How can i do this map iteration in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator

I have a bean say "orderHistory" it has a list "order" and order has "orderitem" list. In orderitem list i have 2 props "orederitemno" Now in my iteration i am getting the "orederitemno" and putting it in a list "orederitemnolist"

OrderHistory->Order->OrderItem->"orederitemno" then put them in seperate lists... PFB the code i am using ,

```
List<String> itemNos = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (Order order : orderHistory.getOrders()) {  
    for (OrderItem item : order.getItems()) {
        itemNos.add(item.getItemNo());
    }
}
```

Now i am passing this list to a method which returns me a map with itemcodes,

`Map itemCodeMap = Myutil.getItemCodes(itemNos);`

Now how to iterate through this map and put the itemcode for each orderItem in the OrderHistory bean ???? Should i use the above loop once again?? ANy suggestion how this can be done...

Note i have added a getter setter for itemcode in OrderItem class... How to set the code against each order item iterating through the map..

Answer (score 1):

> Now how to iterate through this map and put the itemcode for each orderItem in the OrderHistory bean ???? Should i use the above loop once again?? ANy suggestion how this can be done...

Yeah, just do the same loop again, using a guess at the method names:

```
List<String> itemNos = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (Order order : orderHistory.getOrders()) {  
    for (OrderItem item : order.getItems()) {
        ItemCode code = (ItemCode)itemCodeMap.get(item.getItemNo());
        if(code!=null) {
            item.setItemCode(code);
        }
    }
}
```